# SVG <path href=""> Issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG of a map of the united states, split up by state, and I'm trying to make it so when you click each state, you get directed to a specific page, but I'm unsure of how I can attach an href to a  element.

```js
$("path, circle").hover(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','block');
  $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
});

$("path, circle").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','none');
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('top',e.pageY-$('#info-box').height()-30);
  $('#info-box').css('left',e.pageX-($('#info-box').width())/2);
}).mouseover();

var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if(ios) {
  $('a').on('click touchend', function() { 
    var link = $(this).attr('href');   
    window.open(link,'_blank');
    return false;
  });
}
```

```css
#us-map{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
path:hover, circle:hover {
  stroke: #002868 !important;
  stroke-width:2px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: #002868 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#path67 {
  fill: none !important;
  stroke: #A9A9A9 !important;
  cursor: default;
}
#info-box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #BF0A30;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="info-box"></div>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="us-map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" sodipodi:docname="Republican_Party_presidential_primaries_results,_2016.svg" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" x="0px" y="0px" width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="174 100 959 593" enable-background="new 174 100 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
<sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:cx="509.19152" inkscape:cy="282.2353" inkscape:zoom="1.2137643" showgrid="false" id="namedview71" inkscape:current-layer="g5" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:window-height="1017" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:pageshadow="2">
 </sodipodi:namedview>
<g id="g5">
 <path id="HI" data-info="<div>State: Hawaii</div><div>Capital: Honolulu</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9   l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6   l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9   l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8   l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z"/>
 <path id="AK" data-info="<div>State: Alaska</div><div>Capital: Juneau</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M332.1,553.7l-0.3,85.4l1.6,1l3.1,0.2l1.5-1.1h2.6l0.2,2.9l7,6.8l0.5,2.6l3.4-1.9l0.6-0.2l0.3-3.1   l1.5-1.6l1.1-0.2l1.9-1.5l3.1,2.1l0.6,2.9l1.9,1.1l1.1,2.4l3.9,1.8l3.4,6l2.7,3.9l2.3,2.7l1.5,3.7l5,1.8l5.2,2.1l1,4.4l0.5,3.1   l-1,3.4l-1.8,2.3l-1.6-0.8l-1.5-3.1l-2.7-1.5l-1.8-1.1l-0.8,0.8l1.5,2.7l0.2,3.7l-1.1,0.5l-1.9-1.9l-2.1-1.3l0.5,1.6l1.3,1.8   l-0.8,0.8c0,0-0.8-0.3-1.3-1c-0.5-0.6-2.1-3.4-2.1-3.4l-1-2.3c0,0-0.3,1.3-1,1c-0.6-0.3-1.3-1.5-1.3-1.5l1.8-1.9l-1.5-1.5v-5h-0.8   l-0.8,3.4l-1.1,0.5l-1-3.7l-0.6-3.7l-0.8-0.5l0.3,5.7v1.1l-1.5-1.3l-3.6-6l-2.1-0.5l-0.6-3.7l-1.6-2.9l-1.6-1.1v-2.3l2.1-1.3   l-0.5-0.3l-2.6,0.6l-3.4-2.4l-2.6-2.9l-4.8-2.6l-4-2.6l1.3-3.2v-1.6l-1.8,1.6l-2.9,1.1l-3.7-1.1l-5.7-2.4h-5.5l-0.6,0.5l-6.5-3.9   l-2.1-0.3l-2.7-5.8l-3.6,0.3l-3.6,1.5l0.5,4.5l1.1-2.9l1,0.3l-1.5,4.4l3.2-2.7l0.6,1.6l-3.9,4.4l-1.3-0.3l-0.5-1.9l-1.3-0.8   l-1.3,1.1l-2.7-1.8l-3.1,2.1l-1.8,2.1l-3.4,2.1l-4.7-0.2l-0.5-2.1l3.7-0.6v-1.3l-2.3-0.6l1-2.4l2.3-3.9v-1.8l0.2-0.8l4.4-2.3l1,1.3   h2.7l-1.3-2.6l-3.7-0.3l-5,2.7l-2.4,3.4l-1.8,2.6l-1.1,2.3l-4.2,1.5l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.6l2.3,1l0.8,2.1l-2.7,3.2l-6.5,4.2l-7.8,4.2   l-2.1,1.1l-5.3,1.1l-5.3,2.3l1.8,1.3l-1.5,1.5l-0.5,1.1l-2.7-1l-3.2,0.2l-0.8,2.3h-1l0.3-2.4l-3.6,1.3l-2.9,1l-3.4-1.3l-2.9,1.9   h-3.2l-2.1,1.3l-1.6,0.8l-2.1-0.3l-2.6-1.1l-2.3,0.6l-1,1l-1.6-1.1v-1.9l3.1-1.3l6.3,0.6l4.4-1.6l2.1-2.1l2.9-0.6l1.8-0.8l2.7,0.2   l1.6,1.3l1-0.3l2.3-2.7l3.1-1l3.4-0.6l1.3-0.3l0.6,0.5h0.8l1.3-3.7l4-1.5l1.9-3.7l2.3-4.5l1.6-1.5l0.3-2.6l-1.6,1.3l-3.4,0.6   l-0.6-2.4l-1.3-0.3l-1,1l-0.2,2.9l-1.5-0.2l-1.5-5.8l-1.3,1.3l-1.1-0.5l-0.3-1.9l-4,0.2l-2.1,1.1l-2.6-0.3l1.5-1.5l0.5-2.6   l-0.6-1.9l1.5-1l1.3-0.2l-0.6-1.8v-4.4l-1-1l-0.8,1.5h-6.1l-1.5-1.3l-0.6-3.9l-2.1-3.6v-1l2.1-0.8l0.2-2.1l1.1-1.1l-0.8-0.5   l-1.3,0.5l-1.1-2.7l1-5l4.5-3.2l2.6-1.6l1.9-3.7l2.7-1.3l2.6,1.1l0.3,2.4l2.4-0.3l3.2-2.4l1.6,0.6l1,0.6h1.6l2.3-1.3l0.8-4.4   c0,0,0.3-2.9,1-3.4c0.6-0.5,1-1,1-1l-1.1-1.9l-2.6,0.8l-3.2,0.8l-1.9-0.5l-3.6-1.8l-5-0.2l-3.6-3.7l0.5-3.9l0.6-2.4l-2.1-1.8   l-1.9-3.7l0.5-0.8l6.8-0.5h2.1l1,1h0.6l-0.2-1.6l3.9-0.6l2.6,0.3l1.5,1.1l-1.5,2.1l-0.5,1.5l2.7,1.6l5,1.8l1.8-1l-2.3-4.4l-1-3.2   l1-0.8l-3.4-1.9l-0.5-1.1l0.5-1.6l-0.8-3.9l-2.9-4.7l-2.4-4.2l2.9-1.9h3.2l1.8,0.6l4.2-0.2l3.7-3.6l1.1-3.1l3.7-2.4l1.6,1l2.7-0.6   l3.7-2.1l1.1-0.2l1,0.8l4.5-0.2l2.7-3.1h1.1l3.6,2.4l1.9,2.1l-0.5,1.1l0.6,1.1l1.6-1.6l3.9,0.3l0.3,3.7l1.9,1.5l7.1,0.6l6.3,4.2   l1.5-1l5.2,2.6l2.1-0.6l1.9-0.8l4.8,1.9L332.1,553.7z M217,582.6l2.1,5.3l-0.2,1l-2.9-0.3l-1.8-4l-1.8-1.5H210l-0.2-2.6l1.8-2.4   l1.1,2.4l1.5,1.5L217,582.6z M214.4,616.1l3.7,0.8l3.7,1l0.8,1l-1.6,3.7l-3.1-0.2l-3.4-3.6L214.4,616.1z M193.7,602l1.1,2.6   l1.1,1.6l-1.1,0.8l-2.1-3.1V602H193.7z M180,675.1l3.4-2.3l3.4-1l2.6,0.3l0.5,1.6l1.9,0.5l1.9-1.9l-0.3-1.6l2.7-0.6l2.9,2.6   l-1.1,1.8l-4.4,1.1l-2.7-0.5l-3.7-1.1l-4.4,1.5l-1.6,0.3L180,675.1z M228.9,670.6l1.6,1.9l2.1-1.6l-1.5-1.3L228.9,670.6z    M231.8,673.6l1.1-2.3l2.1,0.3l-0.8,1.9H231.8z M255.4,671.7l1.5,1.8l1-1.1l-0.8-1.9L255.4,671.7z M264.2,659.2l1.1,5.8l2.9,0.8   l5-2.9l4.4-2.6l-1.6-2.4l0.5-2.4l-2.1,1.3l-2.9-0.8l1.6-1.1l1.9,0.8l3.9-1.8l0.5-1.5l-2.4-0.8l0.8-1.9l-2.7,1.9l-4.7,3.6l-4.8,2.9   L264.2,659.2z M306.5,639.4l2.4-1.5l-1-1.8l-1.8,1L306.5,639.4z"/>
 <path id="FL" data-info="<div>State: Florida</div><div>Capital: Tallahassee</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M929.4,545.5l2.3,7.3l3.7,9.7l5.3,9.4l3.7,6.3l4.8,5.5l4,3.7l1.6,2.9l-1.1,1.3L953,593l2.9,7.4   l2.9,2.9l2.6,5.3l3.6,5.8l4.5,8.2l1.3,7.6l0.5,12l0.6,1.8l-0.3,3.4l-2.4,1.3l0.3,1.9l-0.6,1.9l0.3,2.4l0.5,1.9l-2.7,3.2l-3.1,1.5   l-3.9,0.2l-1.5,1.6l-2.4,1l-1.3-0.5l-1.1-1l-0.3-2.9l-0.8-3.4l-3.4-5.2l-3.6-2.3l-3.9-0.3l-0.8,1.3l-3.1-4.4l-0.6-3.6l-2.6-4   l-1.8-1.1l-1.6,2.1l-1.8-0.3l-2.1-5l-2.9-3.9l-2.9-5.3l-2.6-3.1l-3.6-3.7l2.1-2.4l3.2-5.5l-0.2-1.6l-4.5-1l-1.6,0.6l0.3,0.6l2.6,1   l-1.5,4.5l-0.8,0.5l-1.8-4l-1.3-4.8l-0.3-2.7l1.5-4.7v-9.5L910,585l-1.3-3.1l-5.2-1.3l-1.9-0.6l-1.6-2.6l-3.4-1.6l-1.1-3.4l-2.7-1   l-2.4-3.7l-4.2-1.5l-2.9-1.5h-2.6l-4,0.8l-0.2,1.9l0.8,1l-0.5,1.1l-3.1-0.2l-3.7,3.6l-3.6,1.9h-3.9l-3.2,1.3l-0.3-2.7l-1.6-1.9   l-2.9-1.1l-1.6-1.5l-8.1-3.9l-7.6-1.8l-4.4,0.6l-6,0.5l-6,2.1l-3.5,0.6l-0.2-8l-2.6-1.9l-1.8-1.8l0.3-3.1l10.2-1.3l25.5-2.9   l6.8-0.6l5.4,0.3l2.6,3.9l1.5,1.5l8.1,0.5l10.8-0.6l21.5-1.3l5.4-0.7l4.6,0l0.2,2.9l3.8,0.8l0.3-4.8l-1.6-4.5l1-0.7l5.1,0.5   L929.4,545.5z M941.9,677.9l2.4-0.6l1.3-0.2l1.5-2.3l2.3-1.6l1.3,0.5l1.7,0.3l0.4,1.1l-3.5,1.2l-4.2,1.5l-2.3,1.2L941.9,677.9z    M955.4,672.9l1.2,1.1l2.7-2.1l5.3-4.2l3.7-3.9l2.5-6.6l1-1.7l0.2-3.4l-0.7,0.5l-1,2.8l-1.5,4.6l-3.2,5.3l-4.4,4.2l-3.4,1.9   L955.4,672.9z"/>
 <path id="SC" data-info="<div>State: South Carolina</div><div>Capital: Columbia</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M935.2,512.9l-1.8,1l-2.6-1.3l-0.6-2.1l-1.3-3.6l-2.3-2.1l-2.6-0.6l-1.6-4.8l-2.7-6l-4.2-1.9   l-2.1-1.9l-1.3-2.6L910,485l-2.3-1.3l-2.3-2.9l-3.1-2.3l-4.5-1.8l-0.5-1.5l-2.4-2.9l-0.5-1.5l-3.4-5.2l-3.4,0.2l-4-2.4l-1.3-1.3   l-0.3-1.8l0.8-1.9l2.3-1l-0.3-2.1l6.1-2.6l9.1-4.5l7.3-0.8l16.5-0.5l2.3,1.9l1.6,3.2l4.4-0.5l12.6-1.5l2.9,0.8l12.6,7.6l10.1,8.1   l-5.4,5.5l-2.6,6.1l-0.5,6.3l-1.6,0.8l-1.1,2.7l-2.4,0.6l-2.1,3.6l-2.7,2.7l-2.3,3.4l-1.6,0.8l-3.6,3.4l-2.9,0.2l1,3.2l-5,5.5   L935.2,512.9z"/>
 <path id="GA" data-info="<div>State: Georgia</div><div>Capital: Atlanta</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M863.6,458l-4.8,0.8l-8.4,1.1l-8.6,0.9v2.2l0.2,2.1l0.6,3.4l3.4,7.9l2.4,9.9l1.5,6.1l1.6,4.8l1.5,7   l2.1,6.3l2.6,3.4l0.5,3.4l1.9,0.8l0.2,2.1l-1.8,4.8l-0.5,3.2l-0.2,1.9l1.6,4.4l0.3,5.3l-0.8,2.4l0.6,0.8l1.5,0.8l0.6,3.4l2.6,3.9   l1.5,1.5l7.9,0.2l10.8-0.6l21.5-1.3l5.4-0.7l4.6,0l0.2,2.9l2.6,0.8l0.3-4.4l-1.6-4.5l1.1-1.6l5.8,0.8l5,0.3l-0.8-6.3l2.3-10   l1.5-4.2l-0.5-2.6l3.3-6.2l-0.5-1.4l-1.9,0.7l-2.6-1.3l-0.6-2.1l-1.3-3.6l-2.3-2.1l-2.6-0.6l-1.6-4.8l-2.9-6.3l-4.2-1.9l-2.1-1.9   l-1.3-2.6l-2.1-1.9l-2.3-1.3l-2.3-2.9l-3.1-2.3l-4.5-1.8l-0.5-1.5l-2.4-2.9l-0.5-1.5l-3.4-4.9l-3.4,0.2l-4.1-3l-1.3-1.3l-0.3-1.8   l0.8-1.9l2.4-1.2l-1.1-1.2l0.1-0.3l-5.8,1l-7,0.8L863.6,458z"/>
 <path id="AL" data-info="<div>State: Alabama</div><div>Capital: Montgomery</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M799.6,566.8l-1.6-15.2l-2.7-18.8l0.2-14.1l0.8-31l-0.2-16.7l0.2-6.4l7.8-0.4l27.8-2.6l8.9-0.7   l-0.1,2.2l0.2,2.1l0.6,3.4l3.4,7.9l2.4,9.9l1.5,6.1l1.6,4.8l1.5,7l2.1,6.3l2.6,3.4l0.5,3.4l1.9,0.8l0.2,2.1l-1.8,4.8l-0.5,3.2   l-0.2,1.9l1.6,4.4l0.3,5.3l-0.8,2.4l0.6,0.8l1.5,0.8l1,2.5h-6.3l-6.8,0.6l-25.5,2.9l-10.4,1.4l-0.1,3.8l1.8,1.8l2.6,1.9l0.6,7.9   l-5.5,2.6l-2.7-0.3l2.7-1.9v-1l-3.1-6l-2.3-0.6l-1.5,4.4l-1.3,2.7l-0.6-0.2H799.6z"/>
 <path id="NC" data-info="<div>State: North Carolina</div><div>Capital: Raleigh</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1006.1,398.5l1.7,4.7l3.6,6.5l2.4,2.4l0.6,2.3l-2.4,0.2l0.8,0.6l-0.3,4.2l-2.6,1.3l-0.6,2.1   l-1.3,2.9l-3.7,1.6l-2.4-0.3l-1.5-0.2l-1.6-1.3l0.3,1.3v1h1.9l0.8,1.3l-1.9,6.3h4.2l0.6,1.6l2.3-2.3l1.3-0.5l-1.9,3.6l-3.1,4.8   h-1.3l-1.1-0.5l-2.7,0.6l-5.2,2.4l-6.5,5.3l-3.4,4.7l-1.9,6.5l-0.5,2.4l-4.7,0.5l-5.5,1.3l-9.9-8.2l-12.6-7.6l-2.9-0.8l-12.6,1.5   l-4.3,0.8l-1.6-3.2l-3-2.1l-16.5,0.5l-7.3,0.8l-9.1,4.5l-6.1,2.6l-1.6,0.3l-5.8,1l-7,0.8l-6.8,0.5l0.5-4.1l1.8-1.5l2.7-0.6l0.6-3.7   l4.2-2.7l3.9-1.5l4.2-3.6l4.4-2.1l0.6-3.1l3.9-3.9l0.6-0.2c0,0,0,1.1,0.8,1.1c0.8,0,1.9,0.3,1.9,0.3l2.3-3.6l2.1-0.6l2.3,0.3   l1.6-3.6l2.9-2.6l0.5-2.1v-4l4.5,0.7l7.1-1.3l15.8-1.9l17.1-2.6l19.9-4l19.7-4.2l11.4-2.8L1006.1,398.5z M1010,431.5l2.6-2.5   l3.2-2.6l1.5-0.6l0.2-2l-0.6-6.1l-1.5-2.3l-0.6-1.9l0.7-0.2l2.7,5.5l0.4,4.4l-0.2,3.4l-3.4,1.5l-2.8,2.4l-1.1,1.2L1010,431.5z"/>
 <path id="TN" data-info="<div>State: Tennessee</div><div>Capital: Nashville</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M871.1,420.6l-51.9,5l-15.8,1.8l-4.6,0.5l-3.9,0v3.9l-8.4,0.5l-7,0.6l-11.1,0.1l-0.3,5.8l-2.1,6.3   l-1,3l-1.3,4.4l-0.3,2.6l-4,2.3l1.5,3.6l-1,4.4l-1,0.8l7.3-0.2l24.1-1.9l5.3-0.2l8.1-0.5l27.8-2.6l10.2-0.8l8.4-1l8.4-1.1l4.8-0.8   l-0.1-4.5l1.8-1.5l2.7-0.6l0.6-3.7l4.2-2.7l3.9-1.5l4.2-3.6l4.4-2.1l0.9-3.5l4.3-3.9l0.6-0.2c0,0,0,1.1,0.8,1.1s1.9,0.3,1.9,0.3   l2.3-3.6l2.1-0.6l2.3,0.3l1.6-3.6l2.1-2.2l0.6-1l0.2-3.9l-1.5-0.3l-2.4,1.9l-7.9,0.2l-12,1.9L871.1,420.6z"/>
 <path id="RI" data-info="<div>State: Rhode Island</div><div>Capital: Providence</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1048.1,279.8l-0.5-4.2l-0.8-4.4l-1.7-5.9l5.7-1.5l1.6,1.1l3.4,4.4l2.9,4.4l-2.9,1.5l-1.3-0.2   l-1.1,1.8l-2.4,1.9L1048.1,279.8z"/>
 <path id="CT" data-info="<div>State: Connecticut</div><div>Capital: Hartford</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1047.2,280.1l-0.6-4.2l-0.8-4.4l-1.6-6l-4.2,0.9l-21.8,4.8l0.6,3.3l1.5,7.3v8.1l-1.1,2.3l1.8,2.1   l5-3.4l3.6-3.2l1.9-2.1l0.8,0.6l2.7-1.5l5.2-1.1L1047.2,280.1z"/>
 <path id="MA" data-info="<div>State: Massachusetts</div><div>Capital: Boston</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1074,273.9l2.2-0.7l0.5-1.7l1,0.1l1,2.3l-1.3,0.5l-3.9,0.1L1074,273.9z M1064.6,274.7l2.3-2.6h1.6   l1.8,1.5l-2.4,1l-2.2,1L1064.6,274.7z M1029.8,252.7l17.5-4.2l2.3-0.6l2.1-3.2l3.7-1.7l2.9,4.4l-2.4,5.2l-0.3,1.5l1.9,2.6l1.1-0.8   h1.8l2.3,2.6l3.9,6l3.6,0.5l2.3-1l1.8-1.8l-0.8-2.7l-2.1-1.6l-1.5,0.8l-1-1.3l0.5-0.5l2.1-0.2l1.8,0.8l1.9,2.4l1,2.9l0.3,2.4   l-4.2,1.5l-3.9,1.9l-3.9,4.5l-1.9,1.5v-1l2.4-1.5l0.5-1.8l-0.8-3.1l-2.9,1.5l-0.8,1.5l0.5,2.3l-2.1,1l-2.7-4.5l-3.4-4.4l-2.1-1.8   l-6.5,1.9l-5.1,1.1l-21.8,4.8l-0.4-4.9l0.6-10.6l5.2-0.9L1029.8,252.7z"/>
 <path id="ME" data-info="<div>State: Maine</div><div>Capital: Augusta</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1097.2,177.3l1.9,2.1l2.3,3.7v1.9l-2.1,4.7l-1.9,0.6l-3.4,3.1l-4.8,5.5c0,0-0.6,0-1.3,0   c-0.6,0-1-2.1-1-2.1l-1.8,0.2l-1,1.5l-2.4,1.5l-1,1.5l1.6,1.5l-0.5,0.6l-0.5,2.7l-1.9-0.2v-1.6l-0.3-1.3l-1.5,0.3l-1.8-3.2   l-2.1,1.3l1.3,1.5l0.3,1.1l-0.8,1.3l0.3,3.1l0.2,1.6l-1.6,2.6l-2.9,0.5l-0.3,2.9l-5.3,3.1l-1.3,0.5l-1.6-1.5l-3.1,3.6l1,3.2   l-1.5,1.3l-0.2,4.4l-1.1,6.3l-2.5-1.2l-0.5-3.1l-3.9-1.1l-0.3-2.7l-7.3-23.4l-4.2-13.6l1.4-0.1l1.5,0.4v-2.6l0.8-5.5l2.6-4.7l1.5-4   l-1.9-2.4v-6l0.8-1l0.8-2.7l-0.2-1.5l-0.2-4.8l1.8-4.8l2.9-8.9l2.1-4.2h1.3l1.3,0.2v1.1l1.3,2.3l2.7,0.6l0.8-0.8v-1l4-2.9l1.8-1.8   l1.5,0.2l6,2.4l1.9,1l9.1,29.9h6l0.8,1.9l0.2,4.8l2.9,2.3h0.8l0.2-0.5l-0.5-1.1L1097.2,177.3z M1076.3,207.5l1.5-1.5l1.4,1.1   l0.6,2.4l-1.7,0.9L1076.3,207.5z M1083,201.6l1.8,1.9c0,0,1.3,0.1,1.3-0.2s0.2-2,0.2-2l0.9-0.8l-0.8-1.8l-2,0.7L1083,201.6z"/>
 <path id="NH" data-info="<div>State: New Hampshire</div><div>Capital: Concord</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1054.8,242.4l0.9-1.1l1.1-3.3l-2.5-0.9l-0.5-3.1l-3.9-1.1l-0.3-2.7l-7.3-23.4l-4.6-14.5l-0.9,0   l-0.6,1.6l-0.6-0.5l-1-1l-1.5,1.9l0,5l0.3,5.7l1.9,2.7v4l-3.7,5.1l-2.6,1.1v1.1l1.1,1.8v8.6l-0.8,9.2l-0.2,4.8l1,1.3l-0.2,4.5   l-0.5,1.8l1.5,0.9l16.4-4.7l2.3-0.6l1.5-2.6L1054.8,242.4z"/>
 <path id="VT" data-info="<div>State: Vermont</div><div>Capital: Montpelier</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1018.3,253.7l-0.8-5.7l-2.4-10l-0.6-0.3l-2.9-1.3l0.8-2.9l-0.8-2.1l-2.7-4.6l1-3.9l-0.8-5.2   l-2.4-6.5l-0.8-4.9l26.2-6.7l0.3,5.8l1.9,2.7v4l-3.7,4l-2.6,1.1v1.1l1.1,1.8v8.6l-0.8,9.2l-0.2,4.8l1,1.3l-0.2,4.5l-0.5,1.8   l0.7,1.6l-7,1.4L1018.3,253.7z"/>
 <path id="NY" data-info="<div>State: New York</div><div>Capital: Albany</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1002.6,289.4l-1.1-1l-2.6-0.2l-2.3-1.9l-1.6-6.1l-3.5,0.1l-2.4-2.7l-19.4,4.4l-43,8.7l-7.5,1.2   l-0.7-6.5l1.4-1.1l1.3-1.1l1-1.6l1.8-1.1l1.9-1.8l0.5-1.6l2.1-2.7l1.1-1l-0.2-1l-1.3-3.1l-1.8-0.2l-1.9-6.1l2.9-1.8l4.4-1.5l4-1.3   l3.2-0.5l6.3-0.2l1.9,1.3l1.6,0.2l2.1-1.3l2.6-1.1l5.2-0.5l2.1-1.8l1.8-3.2l1.6-1.9h2.1l1.9-1.1l0.2-2.3l-1.5-2.1l-0.3-1.5l1.1-2.1   v-1.5h-1.8l-1.8-0.8l-0.8-1.1l-0.2-2.6l5.8-5.5l0.6-0.8l1.5-2.9l2.9-4.5l2.7-3.7l2.1-2.4l2.4-1.8l3.1-1.2l5.5-1.3l3.2,0.2l4.5-1.5   l7.6-2.1l0.5,5l2.4,6.5l0.8,5.2l-1,3.9l2.6,4.5l0.8,2.1l-0.8,2.9l2.9,1.3l0.6,0.3l3.1,11l-0.5,5.1l-0.5,10.8l0.8,5.5l0.8,3.6   l1.5,7.3v8.1l-1.1,2.3l1.8,2l0.8,1.7l-1.9,1.8l0.3,1.3l1.3-0.3l1.5-1.3l2.3-2.6l1.1-0.6l1.6,0.6l2.3,0.2l7.9-3.9l2.9-2.7l1.3-1.5   l4.2,1.6l-3.4,3.6l-3.9,2.9l-7.1,5.3l-2.6,1l-5.8,1.9l-4,1.1l-1.2-0.5l-0.2-3.7l0.5-2.7l-0.2-2.1l-2.8-1.7l-4.5-1l-3.9-1.1   L1002.6,289.4z"/>
 <path id="NJ" data-info="<div>State: New Jersey</div><div>Capital: Trenton</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1002.2,290.3l-2.1,2.4v3.1l-1.9,3.1l-0.2,1.6l1.3,1.3l-0.2,2.4l-2.3,1.1l0.8,2.7l0.2,1.1l2.7,0.3   l1,2.6l3.6,2.4l2.4,1.6v0.8l-3.2,3.1l-1.6,2.3l-1.5,2.7l-2.3,1.3l-1.2,0.7l-0.2,1.2l-0.6,2.6l1.1,2.2l3.2,2.9l4.8,2.3l4,0.6   l0.2,1.5l-0.8,1l0.3,2.7h0.8l2.1-2.4l0.8-4.8l2.7-4l3.1-6.5l1.1-5.5l-0.6-1.1l-0.2-9.4l-1.6-3.4l-1.1,0.8l-2.7,0.3l-0.5-0.5l1.1-1   l2.1-1.9l0.1-1.1l-0.4-3.4l0.5-2.7l-0.2-2.1l-2.6-1.1l-4.5-1l-3.9-1.1L1002.2,290.3z"/>
 <path id="PA" data-info="<div>State: Pennsylvania</div><div>Capital: Harrisburg</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M996.2,326.5l1.1-0.6l2.3-0.6l1.5-2.7l1.6-2.3l3.2-3.1v-0.8l-2.4-1.6l-3.6-2.4l-1-2.6l-2.7-0.3   l-0.2-1.1l-0.8-2.7l2.3-1.1l0.2-2.4l-1.3-1.3l0.2-1.6l1.9-3.1v-3.1l2.3-2.4l0.2-1.1l-2.6-0.2l-2.3-1.9l-2.4-5.3l-3-0.9l-2.3-2.1   l-18.6,4l-43,8.7l-8.9,1.5l-0.5-7.1l-5.5,5.6l-1.3,0.5l-4.2,3l2.9,19.1l2.5,9.7l3.6,19.3l3.3-0.6l11.9-1.5l37.9-7.7l14.9-2.8   l8.3-1.6l0.3-0.2l2.1-1.6L996.2,326.5z"/>
 <path id="DE" data-info="<div>State: Delaware</div><div>Capital: Dover</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M996.4,330.4l0.6-2.1l0-1.2l-1.3-0.1l-2.1,1.6l-1.5,1.5l1.5,4.2l2.3,5.7l2.1,9.7l1.6,6.3l5-0.2   l6.1-1.2l-2.3-7.4l-1,0.5l-3.6-2.4l-1.8-4.7l-1.9-3.6l-2.3-1l-2.1-3.6L996.4,330.4z"/>
 <path id="MD" data-info="<div>State: Maryland</div><div>Capital: Annapolis</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1011,355.3l-6.1,1.3l-5.8,0.2l-1.8-7.1l-2.1-9.7l-2.3-5.7l-1.3-4.4l-7.5,1.6l-14.9,2.8l-37.5,7.6   l1.1,5l1,5.7l0.3-0.3l2.1-2.4l2.3-2.6l2.4-0.6l1.5-1.5l1.8-2.6l1.3,0.6l2.9-0.3l2.6-2.1l2-1.5l1.8-0.5l1.6,1.1l2.9,1.5l1.9,1.8   l1.2,1.5l4.1,1.7v2.9l5.5,1.3l1.1,0.5l1.4-2l2.9,2l-1.3,2.5l-0.8,4l-1.8,2.6v2.1l0.6,1.8l5.1,1.4l4.3-0.1l3.1,1l2.1,0.3l1-2.1   l-1.5-2.1v-1.8l-2.4-2.1l-2.1-5.5l1.3-5.3l-0.2-2.1l-1.3-1.3c0,0,1.5-1.6,1.5-2.3c0-0.6,0.5-2.1,0.5-2.1l1.9-1.3l1.9-1.6l0.5,1   l-1.5,1.6l-1.3,3.7l0.3,1.1l1.8,0.3l0.5,5.5l-2.1,1l0.3,3.6l0.5-0.2l1.1-1.9l1.6,1.8l-1.6,1.3l-0.3,3.4l2.6,3.4l3.9,0.5l1.6-0.8   l3.2,4.2l1.4,0.5l6.7-2.8l2-4L1011,355.3z M994.3,364.3l1.1,2.5l0.2,1.8l1.1,1.9c0,0,0.9-0.9,0.9-1.2c0-0.3-0.7-3.1-0.7-3.1   l-0.7-2.3L994.3,364.3z"/>
 <path id="WV" data-info="<div>State: West Virginia</div><div>Capital: Charleston</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M930.6,342l1.1,4.9l1.1,6.9l3.6-2.7l2.3-3.1l2.5-0.6l1.5-1.5l1.8-2.6l1.2,0.6l2.9-0.3l2.6-2.1   l2-1.5l1.8-0.5l1.3,1l2.2,1.1l1.9,1.8l1.4,1.3l-0.1,4.7l-5.7-3.1l-4.5-1.8l-0.2,5.3l-0.5,2.1l-1.6,2.7l-0.6,1.6l-3.1,2.4l-0.5,2.3   l-3.4,0.3l-0.3,3.1l-1.1,5.5h-2.6l-1.3-0.8l-1.6-2.7l-1.8,0.2l-0.3,4.4l-2.1,6.6l-5,10.8l0.8,1.3l-0.2,2.7l-2.1,1.9l-1.5-0.3   l-3.2,2.4l-2.6-1l-1.8,4.7c0,0-3.7,0.8-4.4,1c-0.6,0.2-2.4-1.3-2.4-1.3l-2.4,2.3l-2.6,0.6l-2.9-0.8l-1.3-1.3l-2.2-3l-3.1-2   l-2.6-2.7l-2.9-3.7l-0.6-2.3l-2.6-1.5l-0.8-1.6l-0.2-5.3l2.2-0.1l1.9-0.8l0.2-2.7l1.6-1.5l0.2-5l1-3.9l1.3-0.6l1.3,1.1l0.5,1.8   l1.8-1l0.5-1.6l-1.1-1.8v-2.4l1-1.3l2.3-3.4l1.3-1.5l2.1,0.5l2.3-1.6l3.1-3.4l2.3-3.9l0.3-5.7l0.5-5v-4.7l-1.1-3.1l1-1.5l1.3-1.3   l3.5,19.8l4.6-0.8L930.6,342z"/>
 <path id="KY" data-info="<div>State: Kentucky</div><div>Capital: Frankfort</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M895.8,397.8l-2.3,2.7l-4.2,3.6L885,410l-1.8,1.8v2.1l-3.9,2.1l-5.7,3.4l-3.5,0.4l-51.9,4.9   l-15.8,1.8l-4.6,0.5l-3.9,0l-0.2,4.2l-8.2,0.1l-7,0.6l-10.4,0.2l1.9-0.2l2.2-1.8l2.1-1.1l0.2-3.2l0.9-1.8l-1.6-2.5l0.8-1.9l2.3-1.8   l2.1-0.6l2.7,1.3l3.6,1.3l1.1-0.3l0.2-2.3l-1.3-2.4l0.3-2.3l1.9-1.5l2.6-0.6l1.6-0.6l-0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.9l1.1-0.8l1.1-3.3l3-1.7   l5.8-1l3.6-0.5l1.5,1.9l1.8,0.8l1.8-3.2l2.9-1.5l1.9,1.6l0.8,1.1l2.1-0.5l-0.2-3.4l2.9-1.6l1.1-0.8l1.1,1.6h4.7l0.8-2.1l-0.3-2.3   l2.9-3.6l4.7-3.9l0.5-4.5l2.7-0.3l3.9-1.8l2.7-1.9l-0.3-1.9l-1.5-1.5l0.6-2.2l4.1-0.2l2.4-0.8l2.9,1.6l1.6,4.4l5.8,0.3l1.8,1.8   l2.1,0.2l2.4-1.5l3.1,0.5l1.3,1.5l2.7-2.6l1.8-1.3h1.6l0.6,2.7l1.8,1l2.4,2.2l0.2,5.5l0.8,1.6l2.6,1.5l0.6,2.3l2.9,3.7l2.6,2.7   L895.8,397.8z"/>
 <path id="OH" data-info="<div>State: Ohio</div><div>Capital: Columbus</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M905.4,295l-6.1,4.1l-3.9,2.3l-3.4,3.7l-4,3.9l-3.2,0.8l-2.9,0.5l-5.5,2.6l-2.1,0.2l-3.4-3.1   l-5.2,0.6l-2.6-1.5l-2.4-1.4l-4.9,0.7l-10.2,1.6l-7.8,1.2l1.3,14.6l1.8,13.7l2.6,23.4l0.6,4.8l4.1-0.1l2.4-0.8l3.4,1.5l2.1,4.4   l5.1,0l1.9,2.1l1.8-0.1l2.5-1.3l2.5,0.4l2,1.5l1.7-2.1l2.3-1.3l2.1-0.7l0.6,2.7l1.8,1l3.5,2.3l2.2-0.1l1.1-1.1l-0.1-1.4l1.6-1.5   l0.2-5l1-3.9l1.5-1.4l1.5,0.9l0.8,1.2l1.2-0.2l-0.4-2.4l-0.6-0.6v-2.4l1-1.3l2.3-3.4l1.3-1.5l2.1,0.5l2.3-1.6l3.1-3.4l2.3-3.9   l0.2-5.4l0.5-5v-4.7l-1.1-3.1l1-1.5l0.9-1l-1.4-9.8L905.4,295z"/>
 <path id="MI" data-info="<div>State: Michigan</div><div>Capital: Lansing</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M755.6,182.1l1.8-2.1l2.2-0.8l5.4-3.9l2.3-0.6l0.5,0.5l-5.1,5.1l-3.3,1.9l-2.1,0.9L755.6,182.1z    M841.8,214.2l0.6,2.5l3.2,0.2l1.3-1.2c0,0-0.1-1.5-0.4-1.6c-0.3-0.2-1.6-1.9-1.6-1.9l-2.2,0.2l-1.6,0.2l-0.3,1.1L841.8,214.2z    M871.9,277.2l-3.2-8.2l-2.3-9.1l-2.4-3.2l-2.6-1.8l-1.6,1.1l-3.9,1.8l-1.9,5l-2.7,3.7l-1.1,0.6l-1.5-0.6c0,0-2.6-1.5-2.4-2.1   c0.2-0.6,0.5-5,0.5-5l3.4-1.3l0.8-3.4l0.6-2.6l2.4-1.6l-0.3-10l-1.6-2.3l-1.3-0.8l-0.8-2.1l0.8-0.8l1.6,0.3l0.2-1.6L850,231   l-1.3-2.6h-2.6l-4.5-1.5l-5.5-3.4h-2.7l-0.6,0.6l-1-0.5l-3.1-2.3l-2.9,1.8l-2.9,2.3l0.3,3.6l1,0.3l2.1,0.5l0.5,0.8l-2.6,0.8   l-2.6,0.3l-1.5,1.8l-0.3,2.1l0.3,1.6l0.3,5.5l-3.6,2.1l-0.6-0.2v-4.2l1.3-2.4l0.6-2.4l-0.8-0.8l-1.9,0.8l-1,4.2l-2.7,1.1l-1.8,1.9   l-0.2,1l0.6,0.8l-0.6,2.6l-2.3,0.5v1.1l0.8,2.4l-1.1,6.1l-1.6,4l0.6,4.7l0.5,1.1l-0.8,2.4l-0.3,0.8l-0.3,2.7l3.6,6l2.9,6.5l1.5,4.8   l-0.8,4.7l-1,6l-2.4,5.2l-0.3,2.7l-3.3,3.1l4.4-0.2l21.4-2.3l7.3-1l0.1,1.7l6.9-1.2l10.3-1.5l3.9-0.5l0.1-0.6l0.2-1.5l2.1-3.7   l2-1.7l-0.2-5.1l1.6-1.6l1.1-0.3l0.2-3.6l1.5-3l1.1,0.6l0.2,0.6l0.8,0.2l1.9-1L871.9,277.2z M741.5,211.2l0.7-0.6l2.7-0.8l3.6-2.3   v-1l0.6-0.6l6-1l2.4-1.9l4.4-2.1l0.2-1.3l1.9-2.9l1.8-0.8l1.3-1.8l2.3-2.3l4.4-2.4l4.7-0.5l1.1,1.1l-0.3,1l-3.7,1l-1.5,3.1   l-2.3,0.8l-0.5,2.4l-2.4,3.2l-0.3,2.6l0.8,0.5l1-1.1l3.6-2.9l1.3,1.3h2.3l3.2,1l1.5,1.1l1.5,3.1l2.7,2.7l3.9-0.2l1.5-1l1.6,1.3   l1.6,0.5l1.3-0.8h1.1l1.6-1l4-3.6l3.4-1.1l6.6-0.3l4.5-1.9l2.6-1.3l1.5,0.2v5.7l0.5,0.3l2.9,0.8l1.9-0.5l6.1-1.6l1.1-1.1l1.5,0.5v7   l3.2,3.1l1.3,0.6l1.3,1l-1.3,0.3l-0.8-0.3l-3.7-0.5l-2.1,0.6l-2.3-0.2l-3.2,1.5h-1.8l-5.8-1.3l-5.2,0.2l-1.9,2.6l-7,0.6l-2.4,0.8   l-1.1,3.1l-1.3,1.1l-0.5-0.2l-1.5-1.6l-4.5,2.4h-0.6l-1.1-1.6l-0.8,0.2l-1.9,4.4l-1,4l-3.2,7l-1.2-1l-1.4-1l-1.9-10.3l-3.5-1.4   l-2.1-2.3l-12.1-2.7l-2.9-1l-8.2-2.2l-7.9-1.1L741.5,211.2z"/>
 <path id="WY" data-info="<div>State: Wyoming</div><div>Capital: Cheyenne</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M528.3,243.8l-10.5-0.8l-32.1-3.3l-16.2-2.1l-28.3-4.1l-19.9-3l-1.4,11.2l-3.8,24.3l-5.3,30.4   l-1.5,10.5l-1.7,11.9l6.5,0.9l25.9,2.5l20.6,2.3l36.8,4.1l23.8,2.9l4.5-44.2l1.4-25.4L528.3,243.8z"/>
 <path id="MT" data-info="<div>State: Montana</div><div>Capital: Helena</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M530.7,222.3l0.6-11.2l2.3-24.8c0.5-5,1.1-8.5,1.4-15.4l0.9-14.6l-30.7-2.8L476,150l-29.3-4   l-32.3-5.3l-18.4-3.4l-32.7-6.9l-4.5,21.3l3.4,7.5l-1.4,4.6l1.8,4.6l3.2,1.4l4.6,10.8l2.7,3.2l0.5,1.1l3.4,1.1l0.5,2.1l-7.1,17.6   v2.5l2.5,3.2h0.9l4.8-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.2,5.3l2.7,12.6l3,2.5l0.9,0.7l1.8,2.3l-0.5,3.4l0.7,3.4l1.1,0.9l2.3-2.3h2.7l3.2,1.6   l2.5-0.9h4.1l3.7,1.6l2.7-0.5l0.5-3l3-0.7l1.4,1.4l0.5,3.2l1.8,1.4l1.5-11.6l20.7,3l28.2,4l16.6,1.9l31.4,3.5l11,1.5l1.1-15.4   L530.7,222.3z"/>
 <path id="ID" data-info="<div>State: Idaho</div><div>Capital: Boise</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M336.1,281c-22.6-4.3-14.1-2.8-21.1-4.4l4.4-17.5l4.3-17.7l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1   l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.3-4.4l0.4-9.7l3.7-16.5   l4.5-20.8l3.8-13.5l0.8-3.8l13,2.5l-4.2,21.5l2.9,7.7l-1.1,4.6l2,4.6l3.2,1.7l4.5,9.8l2.7,3.8l0.6,1.1l3.4,1.1l0.5,2.5l-6.9,16.8   l0.3,3.3l2.7,2.9l1.9,0.5l4.8-3.6l0.4-0.5l0.2,0.8l0.3,4.1l2.6,12.9l3.5,2.7l0.4,0.8l2.1,2.4l-0.8,2.8l0.7,3.8l1.9,0.9l2.1-1.6   l2.6-0.5l3.4,1.6l2.5-0.6l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.9-2.3l2.5-1.6l0.7,1.7l0.6,2.2l2.3,2.5l-3.8,24l-5.1,29l-4.2-0.3l-8.2-1.5   l-9.8-1.8l-12.2-2.4l-12.5-2.5l-8.5-1.8l-9.3-1.7L336.1,281z"/>
 <path id="WA" data-info="<div>State: Washington</div><div>Capital: Olympia</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M267.6,106.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.4l-1,3.9l-4.1,13.8l-4.5,20.8   l-3.2,16.1l-0.4,9.4l-13.2-3.9l-15.6-3.4l-13.7,0.6l-1.6-1.5l-5.3,1.9l-4-0.3l-2.7-1.8l-1.6,0.5l-4.2-0.2l-1.9-1.4l-4.8-1.7   l-1.4-0.2l-5-1.3l-1.8,1.5l-5.7-0.3l-4.8-3.8l0.2-0.8l0.1-7.9l-2.1-3.9l-4.1-0.7l-0.4-2.4l-2.5-0.6l-2.9-0.5l-1.8,1l-2.3-2.9   l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6   l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9   l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5V119l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.8l0.3-0.8L267.6,106.4z M258.1,112.3l2-0.2   l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6   l-1.5-2.3L258.1,112.3z"/>
 <path id="TX" data-info="<div>State: Texas</div><div>Capital: Austin</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M531.1,433.4l22.7,1.1l31.1,1.1l-2.3,23.5l-0.3,18.2l0.1,2.1l4.3,3.8l1.7,0.8l1.8,0.3l0.7-1.3   l0.9,0.9l1.7,0.5l1.6-0.7l1.1,0.4l-0.3,3.4l4.3,1l2.7,0.8l4,0.5l2.2,1.8l3.2-1.6l2.8,0.4l2,2.8l1.1,0.3l-0.2,2l3.1,1.2l2.8-1.8   l1.5,0.4l2.4,0.2l0.4,1.9l4.6,2l2.7-0.2l2-4.1h0.3l1.1,1.9l4.4,1l3.3,1.2l3.3,0.8l2.1-0.8l0.8-2.5h3.7l1.9,0.8l3.1-1.6h0.7l0.4,1.1   h4.3l2.4-1.3l1.7,0.3l1.4,1.9l2.9,1.7l3.5,1.1l2.7,1.4l2.4,1.6l3.3-0.9l1.9,1l0.5,10.1l0.3,9.7l0.7,9.5l0.5,4l2.7,4.6l1.1,4.1   l3.9,6.3l0.5,2.9l0.5,1l-0.7,7.5l-2.7,4.4l1,2.9l-0.4,2.5l-0.8,7.3l-1.4,2.7l0.6,4.4l-5.7,1.6l-9.9,4.5l-1,1.9l-2.6,1.9l-2.1,1.5   l-1.3,0.8l-5.7,5.3l-2.7,2.1l-5.3,3.2l-5.7,2.4l-6.3,3.4l-1.8,1.5l-5.8,3.6l-3.4,0.6l-3.9,5.5l-4,0.3l-1,1.9l2.3,1.9l-1.5,5.5   l-1.3,4.5l-1.1,3.9l-0.8,4.5l0.8,2.4l1.8,7l1,6.1l1.8,2.7l-1,1.5l-3.1,1.9l-5.7-3.9l-5.5-1.1l-1.3,0.5l-3.2-0.6l-4.2-3.1l-5.2-1.1   l-7.6-3.4l-2.1-3.9l-1.3-6.5l-3.2-1.9l-0.6-2.3l0.6-0.6l0.3-3.4l-1.3-0.6l-0.6-1l1.3-4.4l-1.6-2.3l-3.2-1.3l-3.4-4.4l-3.6-6.6   l-4.2-2.6l0.2-1.9l-5.3-12.3l-0.8-4.2l-1.8-1.9l-0.2-1.5l-6-5.3l-2.6-3.1v-1.1l-2.6-2.1l-6.8-1.1l-7.4-0.6l-3.1-2.3l-4.5,1.8   l-3.6,1.5l-2.3,3.2l-1,3.7l-4.4,6.1l-2.4,2.4l-2.6-1l-1.8-1.1l-1.9-0.6l-3.9-2.3v-0.6l-1.8-1.9l-5.2-2.1l-7.4-7.8l-2.3-4.7v-8.1   l-3.2-6.5l-0.5-2.7l-1.6-1l-1.1-2.1l-5-2.1l-1.3-1.6l-7.1-7.9l-1.3-3.2l-4.7-2.3l-1.5-4.4l-2.6-2.9l-1.9-0.5l-0.6-4.7l8,0.7l29,2.7   l29,1.6l2.3-23.8l3.9-55.6l1.6-18.7l1.4,0 M631.2,667.3l-0.6-7.1l-2.7-7.2l-0.6-7l1.5-8.2l3.3-6.9l3.5-5.4l3.2-3.6l0.6,0.2   l-4.8,6.6l-4.4,6.5l-2,6.6l-0.3,5.2l0.9,6.1l2.6,7.2l0.5,5.2l0.2,1.5L631.2,667.3z"/>
 <path id="CA" data-info="<div>State: California</div><div>Capital: Sacramento</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M310.7,486.8l3.8-0.5l1.5-2l0.7-1.9l-3.2-0.1l-1.1-1.8l0.8-1.7l0-6.2l2.2-1.3l2.7-2.6l0.4-4.9   l1.6-3.5l1.9-2.1l3.3-1.7l1.3-0.7l0.8-1.5l-0.9-0.9l-1-1.5l-0.9-5.3l-2.9-5.2l0.1-2.8l-2.2-3.2l-15-23.2l-19.4-28.7l-22.4-33   l-12.7-19.5l1.8-7.2l6.8-25.9l8.1-31.4l-12.4-3.3l-13.5-3.4l-12.6-4.1l-7.5-2.1l-11.4-3l-7.1-2.4l-1.6,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8   l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5   l2.3,4.8l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6   l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9   l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.8l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2   l2.9,4.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L310.7,486.8z M222.8,437l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1   l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L222.8,437z M224.7,437l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L224.7,437z M245.4,456.8l1.8,2.3   l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V456.8z M244,465.5l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9   s0-2.2,0-2.2L244,465.5z"/>
 <path id="AZ" data-info="<div>State: Arizona</div><div>Capital: Phoenix</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M311.7,487.5l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25.1,2.7   l2.5-12.5l3.8-27.2l7-52.9l4.3-31l-24.6-3.7l-27.2-4.6l-33.4-6.3l-2.9,18.1l-0.5,0.5l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1   h-0.9l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7   l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l-0.1,5.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7l-1.5,2.2L311.7,487.5z"/>
 <path id="NV" data-info="<div>State: Nevada</div><div>Capital: Carson City</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M314.7,277.6l21,4.5l9.7,1.9l9.3,1.8l6.6,1.6l-0.6,5.9l-3.5,17.3l-4.1,20l-1.9,9.7l-2.2,13.3   l-3.2,16.4l-3.5,15.7l-2,10.2l-2.5,16.8l-0.5,1.1l-1.1,2.5l-1.9-0.1l-1.1-2.7l-2.7-0.5l-1.4-1l-2,0.3l-0.9,0.7l-1.3,1.3l-0.4,7   l-0.5,1.7l-0.4,12.1l-1.3,1.7l-1.9-2.3l-14.5-22.7l-19.4-29L263.6,349l-12.4-18.6l1.6-6.6l7-25.9l7.9-31.3l33.6,8.1l13.7,3"/>
 <path id="UT" data-info="<div>State: Utah</div><div>Capital: Salt Lake City</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M427,409.3l-24.6-3.5l-26.6-4.9l-33.8-6l1.6-9.2l3.2-15.2L350,354l2.2-13.6l1.9-8.9l3.8-20.5   l3.5-17.5l1.1-5.6l12.7,2.3l12,2.1l10.3,1.8l8.3,1.4l3.7,0.5l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9l-2.1,22l-3.2,22.6   l-3.8,27.8l-1.7,11.1L427,409.3z"/>
 <g id="DC">
  <path id="path58" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M975.8,353.8l-1.1-1.6l-1-0.8l1.1-1.6l2.2,1.5L975.8,353.8z"/>
  <circle id="circle60" data-info="<div>Washington DC</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.5" cx="975.3" cy="351.8" r="5"/>
 </g>
 
 
 
 
 
</g>
<path id="path67" fill="none" stroke="#A9A9A9" stroke-width="2" d="M385,593v55l36,45 M174,525h144l67,68h86l53,54v46"/>

</svg>
```

I expect it to direct to a page I have specified, but despite adding href to the beginning of a specified path, it does nothing once clicked.
I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to get it working. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Some states were removed due to too big of a body size for StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't see any `<a>` tags or `href` attributes in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `onlick` to the path and use some javascript to send the user where you want in the snip below alaska will send you to SO.
I only did Alaska.

```js
$("path, circle").hover(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','block');
  $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
});

$("path, circle").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','none');
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('top',e.pageY-$('#info-box').height()-30);
  $('#info-box').css('left',e.pageX-($('#info-box').width())/2);
}).mouseover();

var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if(ios) {
  $('a').on('click touchend', function() { 
    var link = $(this).attr('href');   
    window.open(link,'_blank');
    return false;
  });
}
```

```css
#us-map{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
path:hover, circle:hover {
  stroke: #002868 !important;
  stroke-width:2px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: #002868 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#path67 {
  fill: none !important;
  stroke: #A9A9A9 !important;
  cursor: default;
}
#info-box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #BF0A30;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="info-box"></div>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="us-map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" sodipodi:docname="Republican_Party_presidential_primaries_results,_2016.svg" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" x="0px" y="0px" width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="174 100 959 593" enable-background="new 174 100 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
<sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:cx="509.19152" inkscape:cy="282.2353" inkscape:zoom="1.2137643" showgrid="false" id="namedview71" inkscape:current-layer="g5" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:window-height="1017" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:pageshadow="2">
 </sodipodi:namedview>
<g id="g5">
 <path id="HI"  data-info="<div>State: Hawaii</div><div>Capital: Honolulu</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9   l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6   l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9   l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8   l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z"/>
 <path id="AK" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';" data-info="<div>State: Alaska</div><div>Capital: Juneau</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M332.1,553.7l-0.3,85.4l1.6,1l3.1,0.2l1.5-1.1h2.6l0.2,2.9l7,6.8l0.5,2.6l3.4-1.9l0.6-0.2l0.3-3.1   l1.5-1.6l1.1-0.2l1.9-1.5l3.1,2.1l0.6,2.9l1.9,1.1l1.1,2.4l3.9,1.8l3.4,6l2.7,3.9l2.3,2.7l1.5,3.7l5,1.8l5.2,2.1l1,4.4l0.5,3.1   l-1,3.4l-1.8,2.3l-1.6-0.8l-1.5-3.1l-2.7-1.5l-1.8-1.1l-0.8,0.8l1.5,2.7l0.2,3.7l-1.1,0.5l-1.9-1.9l-2.1-1.3l0.5,1.6l1.3,1.8   l-0.8,0.8c0,0-0.8-0.3-1.3-1c-0.5-0.6-2.1-3.4-2.1-3.4l-1-2.3c0,0-0.3,1.3-1,1c-0.6-0.3-1.3-1.5-1.3-1.5l1.8-1.9l-1.5-1.5v-5h-0.8   l-0.8,3.4l-1.1,0.5l-1-3.7l-0.6-3.7l-0.8-0.5l0.3,5.7v1.1l-1.5-1.3l-3.6-6l-2.1-0.5l-0.6-3.7l-1.6-2.9l-1.6-1.1v-2.3l2.1-1.3   l-0.5-0.3l-2.6,0.6l-3.4-2.4l-2.6-2.9l-4.8-2.6l-4-2.6l1.3-3.2v-1.6l-1.8,1.6l-2.9,1.1l-3.7-1.1l-5.7-2.4h-5.5l-0.6,0.5l-6.5-3.9   l-2.1-0.3l-2.7-5.8l-3.6,0.3l-3.6,1.5l0.5,4.5l1.1-2.9l1,0.3l-1.5,4.4l3.2-2.7l0.6,1.6l-3.9,4.4l-1.3-0.3l-0.5-1.9l-1.3-0.8   l-1.3,1.1l-2.7-1.8l-3.1,2.1l-1.8,2.1l-3.4,2.1l-4.7-0.2l-0.5-2.1l3.7-0.6v-1.3l-2.3-0.6l1-2.4l2.3-3.9v-1.8l0.2-0.8l4.4-2.3l1,1.3   h2.7l-1.3-2.6l-3.7-0.3l-5,2.7l-2.4,3.4l-1.8,2.6l-1.1,2.3l-4.2,1.5l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.6l2.3,1l0.8,2.1l-2.7,3.2l-6.5,4.2l-7.8,4.2   l-2.1,1.1l-5.3,1.1l-5.3,2.3l1.8,1.3l-1.5,1.5l-0.5,1.1l-2.7-1l-3.2,0.2l-0.8,2.3h-1l0.3-2.4l-3.6,1.3l-2.9,1l-3.4-1.3l-2.9,1.9   h-3.2l-2.1,1.3l-1.6,0.8l-2.1-0.3l-2.6-1.1l-2.3,0.6l-1,1l-1.6-1.1v-1.9l3.1-1.3l6.3,0.6l4.4-1.6l2.1-2.1l2.9-0.6l1.8-0.8l2.7,0.2   l1.6,1.3l1-0.3l2.3-2.7l3.1-1l3.4-0.6l1.3-0.3l0.6,0.5h0.8l1.3-3.7l4-1.5l1.9-3.7l2.3-4.5l1.6-1.5l0.3-2.6l-1.6,1.3l-3.4,0.6   l-0.6-2.4l-1.3-0.3l-1,1l-0.2,2.9l-1.5-0.2l-1.5-5.8l-1.3,1.3l-1.1-0.5l-0.3-1.9l-4,0.2l-2.1,1.1l-2.6-0.3l1.5-1.5l0.5-2.6   l-0.6-1.9l1.5-1l1.3-0.2l-0.6-1.8v-4.4l-1-1l-0.8,1.5h-6.1l-1.5-1.3l-0.6-3.9l-2.1-3.6v-1l2.1-0.8l0.2-2.1l1.1-1.1l-0.8-0.5   l-1.3,0.5l-1.1-2.7l1-5l4.5-3.2l2.6-1.6l1.9-3.7l2.7-1.3l2.6,1.1l0.3,2.4l2.4-0.3l3.2-2.4l1.6,0.6l1,0.6h1.6l2.3-1.3l0.8-4.4   c0,0,0.3-2.9,1-3.4c0.6-0.5,1-1,1-1l-1.1-1.9l-2.6,0.8l-3.2,0.8l-1.9-0.5l-3.6-1.8l-5-0.2l-3.6-3.7l0.5-3.9l0.6-2.4l-2.1-1.8   l-1.9-3.7l0.5-0.8l6.8-0.5h2.1l1,1h0.6l-0.2-1.6l3.9-0.6l2.6,0.3l1.5,1.1l-1.5,2.1l-0.5,1.5l2.7,1.6l5,1.8l1.8-1l-2.3-4.4l-1-3.2   l1-0.8l-3.4-1.9l-0.5-1.1l0.5-1.6l-0.8-3.9l-2.9-4.7l-2.4-4.2l2.9-1.9h3.2l1.8,0.6l4.2-0.2l3.7-3.6l1.1-3.1l3.7-2.4l1.6,1l2.7-0.6   l3.7-2.1l1.1-0.2l1,0.8l4.5-0.2l2.7-3.1h1.1l3.6,2.4l1.9,2.1l-0.5,1.1l0.6,1.1l1.6-1.6l3.9,0.3l0.3,3.7l1.9,1.5l7.1,0.6l6.3,4.2   l1.5-1l5.2,2.6l2.1-0.6l1.9-0.8l4.8,1.9L332.1,553.7z M217,582.6l2.1,5.3l-0.2,1l-2.9-0.3l-1.8-4l-1.8-1.5H210l-0.2-2.6l1.8-2.4   l1.1,2.4l1.5,1.5L217,582.6z M214.4,616.1l3.7,0.8l3.7,1l0.8,1l-1.6,3.7l-3.1-0.2l-3.4-3.6L214.4,616.1z M193.7,602l1.1,2.6   l1.1,1.6l-1.1,0.8l-2.1-3.1V602H193.7z M180,675.1l3.4-2.3l3.4-1l2.6,0.3l0.5,1.6l1.9,0.5l1.9-1.9l-0.3-1.6l2.7-0.6l2.9,2.6   l-1.1,1.8l-4.4,1.1l-2.7-0.5l-3.7-1.1l-4.4,1.5l-1.6,0.3L180,675.1z M228.9,670.6l1.6,1.9l2.1-1.6l-1.5-1.3L228.9,670.6z    M231.8,673.6l1.1-2.3l2.1,0.3l-0.8,1.9H231.8z M255.4,671.7l1.5,1.8l1-1.1l-0.8-1.9L255.4,671.7z M264.2,659.2l1.1,5.8l2.9,0.8   l5-2.9l4.4-2.6l-1.6-2.4l0.5-2.4l-2.1,1.3l-2.9-0.8l1.6-1.1l1.9,0.8l3.9-1.8l0.5-1.5l-2.4-0.8l0.8-1.9l-2.7,1.9l-4.7,3.6l-4.8,2.9   L264.2,659.2z M306.5,639.4l2.4-1.5l-1-1.8l-1.8,1L306.5,639.4z"/>
 <path id="FL" data-info="<div>State: Florida</div><div>Capital: Tallahassee</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M929.4,545.5l2.3,7.3l3.7,9.7l5.3,9.4l3.7,6.3l4.8,5.5l4,3.7l1.6,2.9l-1.1,1.3L953,593l2.9,7.4   l2.9,2.9l2.6,5.3l3.6,5.8l4.5,8.2l1.3,7.6l0.5,12l0.6,1.8l-0.3,3.4l-2.4,1.3l0.3,1.9l-0.6,1.9l0.3,2.4l0.5,1.9l-2.7,3.2l-3.1,1.5   l-3.9,0.2l-1.5,1.6l-2.4,1l-1.3-0.5l-1.1-1l-0.3-2.9l-0.8-3.4l-3.4-5.2l-3.6-2.3l-3.9-0.3l-0.8,1.3l-3.1-4.4l-0.6-3.6l-2.6-4   l-1.8-1.1l-1.6,2.1l-1.8-0.3l-2.1-5l-2.9-3.9l-2.9-5.3l-2.6-3.1l-3.6-3.7l2.1-2.4l3.2-5.5l-0.2-1.6l-4.5-1l-1.6,0.6l0.3,0.6l2.6,1   l-1.5,4.5l-0.8,0.5l-1.8-4l-1.3-4.8l-0.3-2.7l1.5-4.7v-9.5L910,585l-1.3-3.1l-5.2-1.3l-1.9-0.6l-1.6-2.6l-3.4-1.6l-1.1-3.4l-2.7-1   l-2.4-3.7l-4.2-1.5l-2.9-1.5h-2.6l-4,0.8l-0.2,1.9l0.8,1l-0.5,1.1l-3.1-0.2l-3.7,3.6l-3.6,1.9h-3.9l-3.2,1.3l-0.3-2.7l-1.6-1.9   l-2.9-1.1l-1.6-1.5l-8.1-3.9l-7.6-1.8l-4.4,0.6l-6,0.5l-6,2.1l-3.5,0.6l-0.2-8l-2.6-1.9l-1.8-1.8l0.3-3.1l10.2-1.3l25.5-2.9   l6.8-0.6l5.4,0.3l2.6,3.9l1.5,1.5l8.1,0.5l10.8-0.6l21.5-1.3l5.4-0.7l4.6,0l0.2,2.9l3.8,0.8l0.3-4.8l-1.6-4.5l1-0.7l5.1,0.5   L929.4,545.5z M941.9,677.9l2.4-0.6l1.3-0.2l1.5-2.3l2.3-1.6l1.3,0.5l1.7,0.3l0.4,1.1l-3.5,1.2l-4.2,1.5l-2.3,1.2L941.9,677.9z    M955.4,672.9l1.2,1.1l2.7-2.1l5.3-4.2l3.7-3.9l2.5-6.6l1-1.7l0.2-3.4l-0.7,0.5l-1,2.8l-1.5,4.6l-3.2,5.3l-4.4,4.2l-3.4,1.9   L955.4,672.9z"/>
 <path id="SC" data-info="<div>State: South Carolina</div><div>Capital: Columbia</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M935.2,512.9l-1.8,1l-2.6-1.3l-0.6-2.1l-1.3-3.6l-2.3-2.1l-2.6-0.6l-1.6-4.8l-2.7-6l-4.2-1.9   l-2.1-1.9l-1.3-2.6L910,485l-2.3-1.3l-2.3-2.9l-3.1-2.3l-4.5-1.8l-0.5-1.5l-2.4-2.9l-0.5-1.5l-3.4-5.2l-3.4,0.2l-4-2.4l-1.3-1.3   l-0.3-1.8l0.8-1.9l2.3-1l-0.3-2.1l6.1-2.6l9.1-4.5l7.3-0.8l16.5-0.5l2.3,1.9l1.6,3.2l4.4-0.5l12.6-1.5l2.9,0.8l12.6,7.6l10.1,8.1   l-5.4,5.5l-2.6,6.1l-0.5,6.3l-1.6,0.8l-1.1,2.7l-2.4,0.6l-2.1,3.6l-2.7,2.7l-2.3,3.4l-1.6,0.8l-3.6,3.4l-2.9,0.2l1,3.2l-5,5.5   L935.2,512.9z"/>
 <path id="GA" data-info="<div>State: Georgia</div><div>Capital: Atlanta</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M863.6,458l-4.8,0.8l-8.4,1.1l-8.6,0.9v2.2l0.2,2.1l0.6,3.4l3.4,7.9l2.4,9.9l1.5,6.1l1.6,4.8l1.5,7   l2.1,6.3l2.6,3.4l0.5,3.4l1.9,0.8l0.2,2.1l-1.8,4.8l-0.5,3.2l-0.2,1.9l1.6,4.4l0.3,5.3l-0.8,2.4l0.6,0.8l1.5,0.8l0.6,3.4l2.6,3.9   l1.5,1.5l7.9,0.2l10.8-0.6l21.5-1.3l5.4-0.7l4.6,0l0.2,2.9l2.6,0.8l0.3-4.4l-1.6-4.5l1.1-1.6l5.8,0.8l5,0.3l-0.8-6.3l2.3-10   l1.5-4.2l-0.5-2.6l3.3-6.2l-0.5-1.4l-1.9,0.7l-2.6-1.3l-0.6-2.1l-1.3-3.6l-2.3-2.1l-2.6-0.6l-1.6-4.8l-2.9-6.3l-4.2-1.9l-2.1-1.9   l-1.3-2.6l-2.1-1.9l-2.3-1.3l-2.3-2.9l-3.1-2.3l-4.5-1.8l-0.5-1.5l-2.4-2.9l-0.5-1.5l-3.4-4.9l-3.4,0.2l-4.1-3l-1.3-1.3l-0.3-1.8   l0.8-1.9l2.4-1.2l-1.1-1.2l0.1-0.3l-5.8,1l-7,0.8L863.6,458z"/>
 <path id="AL" data-info="<div>State: Alabama</div><div>Capital: Montgomery</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M799.6,566.8l-1.6-15.2l-2.7-18.8l0.2-14.1l0.8-31l-0.2-16.7l0.2-6.4l7.8-0.4l27.8-2.6l8.9-0.7   l-0.1,2.2l0.2,2.1l0.6,3.4l3.4,7.9l2.4,9.9l1.5,6.1l1.6,4.8l1.5,7l2.1,6.3l2.6,3.4l0.5,3.4l1.9,0.8l0.2,2.1l-1.8,4.8l-0.5,3.2   l-0.2,1.9l1.6,4.4l0.3,5.3l-0.8,2.4l0.6,0.8l1.5,0.8l1,2.5h-6.3l-6.8,0.6l-25.5,2.9l-10.4,1.4l-0.1,3.8l1.8,1.8l2.6,1.9l0.6,7.9   l-5.5,2.6l-2.7-0.3l2.7-1.9v-1l-3.1-6l-2.3-0.6l-1.5,4.4l-1.3,2.7l-0.6-0.2H799.6z"/>
 <path id="NC" data-info="<div>State: North Carolina</div><div>Capital: Raleigh</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1006.1,398.5l1.7,4.7l3.6,6.5l2.4,2.4l0.6,2.3l-2.4,0.2l0.8,0.6l-0.3,4.2l-2.6,1.3l-0.6,2.1   l-1.3,2.9l-3.7,1.6l-2.4-0.3l-1.5-0.2l-1.6-1.3l0.3,1.3v1h1.9l0.8,1.3l-1.9,6.3h4.2l0.6,1.6l2.3-2.3l1.3-0.5l-1.9,3.6l-3.1,4.8   h-1.3l-1.1-0.5l-2.7,0.6l-5.2,2.4l-6.5,5.3l-3.4,4.7l-1.9,6.5l-0.5,2.4l-4.7,0.5l-5.5,1.3l-9.9-8.2l-12.6-7.6l-2.9-0.8l-12.6,1.5   l-4.3,0.8l-1.6-3.2l-3-2.1l-16.5,0.5l-7.3,0.8l-9.1,4.5l-6.1,2.6l-1.6,0.3l-5.8,1l-7,0.8l-6.8,0.5l0.5-4.1l1.8-1.5l2.7-0.6l0.6-3.7   l4.2-2.7l3.9-1.5l4.2-3.6l4.4-2.1l0.6-3.1l3.9-3.9l0.6-0.2c0,0,0,1.1,0.8,1.1c0.8,0,1.9,0.3,1.9,0.3l2.3-3.6l2.1-0.6l2.3,0.3   l1.6-3.6l2.9-2.6l0.5-2.1v-4l4.5,0.7l7.1-1.3l15.8-1.9l17.1-2.6l19.9-4l19.7-4.2l11.4-2.8L1006.1,398.5z M1010,431.5l2.6-2.5   l3.2-2.6l1.5-0.6l0.2-2l-0.6-6.1l-1.5-2.3l-0.6-1.9l0.7-0.2l2.7,5.5l0.4,4.4l-0.2,3.4l-3.4,1.5l-2.8,2.4l-1.1,1.2L1010,431.5z"/>
 <path id="TN" data-info="<div>State: Tennessee</div><div>Capital: Nashville</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M871.1,420.6l-51.9,5l-15.8,1.8l-4.6,0.5l-3.9,0v3.9l-8.4,0.5l-7,0.6l-11.1,0.1l-0.3,5.8l-2.1,6.3   l-1,3l-1.3,4.4l-0.3,2.6l-4,2.3l1.5,3.6l-1,4.4l-1,0.8l7.3-0.2l24.1-1.9l5.3-0.2l8.1-0.5l27.8-2.6l10.2-0.8l8.4-1l8.4-1.1l4.8-0.8   l-0.1-4.5l1.8-1.5l2.7-0.6l0.6-3.7l4.2-2.7l3.9-1.5l4.2-3.6l4.4-2.1l0.9-3.5l4.3-3.9l0.6-0.2c0,0,0,1.1,0.8,1.1s1.9,0.3,1.9,0.3   l2.3-3.6l2.1-0.6l2.3,0.3l1.6-3.6l2.1-2.2l0.6-1l0.2-3.9l-1.5-0.3l-2.4,1.9l-7.9,0.2l-12,1.9L871.1,420.6z"/>
 <path id="RI" data-info="<div>State: Rhode Island</div><div>Capital: Providence</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1048.1,279.8l-0.5-4.2l-0.8-4.4l-1.7-5.9l5.7-1.5l1.6,1.1l3.4,4.4l2.9,4.4l-2.9,1.5l-1.3-0.2   l-1.1,1.8l-2.4,1.9L1048.1,279.8z"/>
 <path id="CT" data-info="<div>State: Connecticut</div><div>Capital: Hartford</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1047.2,280.1l-0.6-4.2l-0.8-4.4l-1.6-6l-4.2,0.9l-21.8,4.8l0.6,3.3l1.5,7.3v8.1l-1.1,2.3l1.8,2.1   l5-3.4l3.6-3.2l1.9-2.1l0.8,0.6l2.7-1.5l5.2-1.1L1047.2,280.1z"/>
 <path id="MA" data-info="<div>State: Massachusetts</div><div>Capital: Boston</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1074,273.9l2.2-0.7l0.5-1.7l1,0.1l1,2.3l-1.3,0.5l-3.9,0.1L1074,273.9z M1064.6,274.7l2.3-2.6h1.6   l1.8,1.5l-2.4,1l-2.2,1L1064.6,274.7z M1029.8,252.7l17.5-4.2l2.3-0.6l2.1-3.2l3.7-1.7l2.9,4.4l-2.4,5.2l-0.3,1.5l1.9,2.6l1.1-0.8   h1.8l2.3,2.6l3.9,6l3.6,0.5l2.3-1l1.8-1.8l-0.8-2.7l-2.1-1.6l-1.5,0.8l-1-1.3l0.5-0.5l2.1-0.2l1.8,0.8l1.9,2.4l1,2.9l0.3,2.4   l-4.2,1.5l-3.9,1.9l-3.9,4.5l-1.9,1.5v-1l2.4-1.5l0.5-1.8l-0.8-3.1l-2.9,1.5l-0.8,1.5l0.5,2.3l-2.1,1l-2.7-4.5l-3.4-4.4l-2.1-1.8   l-6.5,1.9l-5.1,1.1l-21.8,4.8l-0.4-4.9l0.6-10.6l5.2-0.9L1029.8,252.7z"/>
 <path id="ME" data-info="<div>State: Maine</div><div>Capital: Augusta</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1097.2,177.3l1.9,2.1l2.3,3.7v1.9l-2.1,4.7l-1.9,0.6l-3.4,3.1l-4.8,5.5c0,0-0.6,0-1.3,0   c-0.6,0-1-2.1-1-2.1l-1.8,0.2l-1,1.5l-2.4,1.5l-1,1.5l1.6,1.5l-0.5,0.6l-0.5,2.7l-1.9-0.2v-1.6l-0.3-1.3l-1.5,0.3l-1.8-3.2   l-2.1,1.3l1.3,1.5l0.3,1.1l-0.8,1.3l0.3,3.1l0.2,1.6l-1.6,2.6l-2.9,0.5l-0.3,2.9l-5.3,3.1l-1.3,0.5l-1.6-1.5l-3.1,3.6l1,3.2   l-1.5,1.3l-0.2,4.4l-1.1,6.3l-2.5-1.2l-0.5-3.1l-3.9-1.1l-0.3-2.7l-7.3-23.4l-4.2-13.6l1.4-0.1l1.5,0.4v-2.6l0.8-5.5l2.6-4.7l1.5-4   l-1.9-2.4v-6l0.8-1l0.8-2.7l-0.2-1.5l-0.2-4.8l1.8-4.8l2.9-8.9l2.1-4.2h1.3l1.3,0.2v1.1l1.3,2.3l2.7,0.6l0.8-0.8v-1l4-2.9l1.8-1.8   l1.5,0.2l6,2.4l1.9,1l9.1,29.9h6l0.8,1.9l0.2,4.8l2.9,2.3h0.8l0.2-0.5l-0.5-1.1L1097.2,177.3z M1076.3,207.5l1.5-1.5l1.4,1.1   l0.6,2.4l-1.7,0.9L1076.3,207.5z M1083,201.6l1.8,1.9c0,0,1.3,0.1,1.3-0.2s0.2-2,0.2-2l0.9-0.8l-0.8-1.8l-2,0.7L1083,201.6z"/>
 <path id="NH" data-info="<div>State: New Hampshire</div><div>Capital: Concord</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1054.8,242.4l0.9-1.1l1.1-3.3l-2.5-0.9l-0.5-3.1l-3.9-1.1l-0.3-2.7l-7.3-23.4l-4.6-14.5l-0.9,0   l-0.6,1.6l-0.6-0.5l-1-1l-1.5,1.9l0,5l0.3,5.7l1.9,2.7v4l-3.7,5.1l-2.6,1.1v1.1l1.1,1.8v8.6l-0.8,9.2l-0.2,4.8l1,1.3l-0.2,4.5   l-0.5,1.8l1.5,0.9l16.4-4.7l2.3-0.6l1.5-2.6L1054.8,242.4z"/>
 <path id="VT" data-info="<div>State: Vermont</div><div>Capital: Montpelier</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1018.3,253.7l-0.8-5.7l-2.4-10l-0.6-0.3l-2.9-1.3l0.8-2.9l-0.8-2.1l-2.7-4.6l1-3.9l-0.8-5.2   l-2.4-6.5l-0.8-4.9l26.2-6.7l0.3,5.8l1.9,2.7v4l-3.7,4l-2.6,1.1v1.1l1.1,1.8v8.6l-0.8,9.2l-0.2,4.8l1,1.3l-0.2,4.5l-0.5,1.8   l0.7,1.6l-7,1.4L1018.3,253.7z"/>
 <path id="NY" data-info="<div>State: New York</div><div>Capital: Albany</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1002.6,289.4l-1.1-1l-2.6-0.2l-2.3-1.9l-1.6-6.1l-3.5,0.1l-2.4-2.7l-19.4,4.4l-43,8.7l-7.5,1.2   l-0.7-6.5l1.4-1.1l1.3-1.1l1-1.6l1.8-1.1l1.9-1.8l0.5-1.6l2.1-2.7l1.1-1l-0.2-1l-1.3-3.1l-1.8-0.2l-1.9-6.1l2.9-1.8l4.4-1.5l4-1.3   l3.2-0.5l6.3-0.2l1.9,1.3l1.6,0.2l2.1-1.3l2.6-1.1l5.2-0.5l2.1-1.8l1.8-3.2l1.6-1.9h2.1l1.9-1.1l0.2-2.3l-1.5-2.1l-0.3-1.5l1.1-2.1   v-1.5h-1.8l-1.8-0.8l-0.8-1.1l-0.2-2.6l5.8-5.5l0.6-0.8l1.5-2.9l2.9-4.5l2.7-3.7l2.1-2.4l2.4-1.8l3.1-1.2l5.5-1.3l3.2,0.2l4.5-1.5   l7.6-2.1l0.5,5l2.4,6.5l0.8,5.2l-1,3.9l2.6,4.5l0.8,2.1l-0.8,2.9l2.9,1.3l0.6,0.3l3.1,11l-0.5,5.1l-0.5,10.8l0.8,5.5l0.8,3.6   l1.5,7.3v8.1l-1.1,2.3l1.8,2l0.8,1.7l-1.9,1.8l0.3,1.3l1.3-0.3l1.5-1.3l2.3-2.6l1.1-0.6l1.6,0.6l2.3,0.2l7.9-3.9l2.9-2.7l1.3-1.5   l4.2,1.6l-3.4,3.6l-3.9,2.9l-7.1,5.3l-2.6,1l-5.8,1.9l-4,1.1l-1.2-0.5l-0.2-3.7l0.5-2.7l-0.2-2.1l-2.8-1.7l-4.5-1l-3.9-1.1   L1002.6,289.4z"/>
 <path id="NJ" data-info="<div>State: New Jersey</div><div>Capital: Trenton</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1002.2,290.3l-2.1,2.4v3.1l-1.9,3.1l-0.2,1.6l1.3,1.3l-0.2,2.4l-2.3,1.1l0.8,2.7l0.2,1.1l2.7,0.3   l1,2.6l3.6,2.4l2.4,1.6v0.8l-3.2,3.1l-1.6,2.3l-1.5,2.7l-2.3,1.3l-1.2,0.7l-0.2,1.2l-0.6,2.6l1.1,2.2l3.2,2.9l4.8,2.3l4,0.6   l0.2,1.5l-0.8,1l0.3,2.7h0.8l2.1-2.4l0.8-4.8l2.7-4l3.1-6.5l1.1-5.5l-0.6-1.1l-0.2-9.4l-1.6-3.4l-1.1,0.8l-2.7,0.3l-0.5-0.5l1.1-1   l2.1-1.9l0.1-1.1l-0.4-3.4l0.5-2.7l-0.2-2.1l-2.6-1.1l-4.5-1l-3.9-1.1L1002.2,290.3z"/>
 <path id="PA" data-info="<div>State: Pennsylvania</div><div>Capital: Harrisburg</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M996.2,326.5l1.1-0.6l2.3-0.6l1.5-2.7l1.6-2.3l3.2-3.1v-0.8l-2.4-1.6l-3.6-2.4l-1-2.6l-2.7-0.3   l-0.2-1.1l-0.8-2.7l2.3-1.1l0.2-2.4l-1.3-1.3l0.2-1.6l1.9-3.1v-3.1l2.3-2.4l0.2-1.1l-2.6-0.2l-2.3-1.9l-2.4-5.3l-3-0.9l-2.3-2.1   l-18.6,4l-43,8.7l-8.9,1.5l-0.5-7.1l-5.5,5.6l-1.3,0.5l-4.2,3l2.9,19.1l2.5,9.7l3.6,19.3l3.3-0.6l11.9-1.5l37.9-7.7l14.9-2.8   l8.3-1.6l0.3-0.2l2.1-1.6L996.2,326.5z"/>
 <path id="DE" data-info="<div>State: Delaware</div><div>Capital: Dover</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M996.4,330.4l0.6-2.1l0-1.2l-1.3-0.1l-2.1,1.6l-1.5,1.5l1.5,4.2l2.3,5.7l2.1,9.7l1.6,6.3l5-0.2   l6.1-1.2l-2.3-7.4l-1,0.5l-3.6-2.4l-1.8-4.7l-1.9-3.6l-2.3-1l-2.1-3.6L996.4,330.4z"/>
 <path id="MD" data-info="<div>State: Maryland</div><div>Capital: Annapolis</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1011,355.3l-6.1,1.3l-5.8,0.2l-1.8-7.1l-2.1-9.7l-2.3-5.7l-1.3-4.4l-7.5,1.6l-14.9,2.8l-37.5,7.6   l1.1,5l1,5.7l0.3-0.3l2.1-2.4l2.3-2.6l2.4-0.6l1.5-1.5l1.8-2.6l1.3,0.6l2.9-0.3l2.6-2.1l2-1.5l1.8-0.5l1.6,1.1l2.9,1.5l1.9,1.8   l1.2,1.5l4.1,1.7v2.9l5.5,1.3l1.1,0.5l1.4-2l2.9,2l-1.3,2.5l-0.8,4l-1.8,2.6v2.1l0.6,1.8l5.1,1.4l4.3-0.1l3.1,1l2.1,0.3l1-2.1   l-1.5-2.1v-1.8l-2.4-2.1l-2.1-5.5l1.3-5.3l-0.2-2.1l-1.3-1.3c0,0,1.5-1.6,1.5-2.3c0-0.6,0.5-2.1,0.5-2.1l1.9-1.3l1.9-1.6l0.5,1   l-1.5,1.6l-1.3,3.7l0.3,1.1l1.8,0.3l0.5,5.5l-2.1,1l0.3,3.6l0.5-0.2l1.1-1.9l1.6,1.8l-1.6,1.3l-0.3,3.4l2.6,3.4l3.9,0.5l1.6-0.8   l3.2,4.2l1.4,0.5l6.7-2.8l2-4L1011,355.3z M994.3,364.3l1.1,2.5l0.2,1.8l1.1,1.9c0,0,0.9-0.9,0.9-1.2c0-0.3-0.7-3.1-0.7-3.1   l-0.7-2.3L994.3,364.3z"/>
 <path id="WV" data-info="<div>State: West Virginia</div><div>Capital: Charleston</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M930.6,342l1.1,4.9l1.1,6.9l3.6-2.7l2.3-3.1l2.5-0.6l1.5-1.5l1.8-2.6l1.2,0.6l2.9-0.3l2.6-2.1   l2-1.5l1.8-0.5l1.3,1l2.2,1.1l1.9,1.8l1.4,1.3l-0.1,4.7l-5.7-3.1l-4.5-1.8l-0.2,5.3l-0.5,2.1l-1.6,2.7l-0.6,1.6l-3.1,2.4l-0.5,2.3   l-3.4,0.3l-0.3,3.1l-1.1,5.5h-2.6l-1.3-0.8l-1.6-2.7l-1.8,0.2l-0.3,4.4l-2.1,6.6l-5,10.8l0.8,1.3l-0.2,2.7l-2.1,1.9l-1.5-0.3   l-3.2,2.4l-2.6-1l-1.8,4.7c0,0-3.7,0.8-4.4,1c-0.6,0.2-2.4-1.3-2.4-1.3l-2.4,2.3l-2.6,0.6l-2.9-0.8l-1.3-1.3l-2.2-3l-3.1-2   l-2.6-2.7l-2.9-3.7l-0.6-2.3l-2.6-1.5l-0.8-1.6l-0.2-5.3l2.2-0.1l1.9-0.8l0.2-2.7l1.6-1.5l0.2-5l1-3.9l1.3-0.6l1.3,1.1l0.5,1.8   l1.8-1l0.5-1.6l-1.1-1.8v-2.4l1-1.3l2.3-3.4l1.3-1.5l2.1,0.5l2.3-1.6l3.1-3.4l2.3-3.9l0.3-5.7l0.5-5v-4.7l-1.1-3.1l1-1.5l1.3-1.3   l3.5,19.8l4.6-0.8L930.6,342z"/>
 <path id="KY" data-info="<div>State: Kentucky</div><div>Capital: Frankfort</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M895.8,397.8l-2.3,2.7l-4.2,3.6L885,410l-1.8,1.8v2.1l-3.9,2.1l-5.7,3.4l-3.5,0.4l-51.9,4.9   l-15.8,1.8l-4.6,0.5l-3.9,0l-0.2,4.2l-8.2,0.1l-7,0.6l-10.4,0.2l1.9-0.2l2.2-1.8l2.1-1.1l0.2-3.2l0.9-1.8l-1.6-2.5l0.8-1.9l2.3-1.8   l2.1-0.6l2.7,1.3l3.6,1.3l1.1-0.3l0.2-2.3l-1.3-2.4l0.3-2.3l1.9-1.5l2.6-0.6l1.6-0.6l-0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.9l1.1-0.8l1.1-3.3l3-1.7   l5.8-1l3.6-0.5l1.5,1.9l1.8,0.8l1.8-3.2l2.9-1.5l1.9,1.6l0.8,1.1l2.1-0.5l-0.2-3.4l2.9-1.6l1.1-0.8l1.1,1.6h4.7l0.8-2.1l-0.3-2.3   l2.9-3.6l4.7-3.9l0.5-4.5l2.7-0.3l3.9-1.8l2.7-1.9l-0.3-1.9l-1.5-1.5l0.6-2.2l4.1-0.2l2.4-0.8l2.9,1.6l1.6,4.4l5.8,0.3l1.8,1.8   l2.1,0.2l2.4-1.5l3.1,0.5l1.3,1.5l2.7-2.6l1.8-1.3h1.6l0.6,2.7l1.8,1l2.4,2.2l0.2,5.5l0.8,1.6l2.6,1.5l0.6,2.3l2.9,3.7l2.6,2.7   L895.8,397.8z"/>
 <path id="OH" data-info="<div>State: Ohio</div><div>Capital: Columbus</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M905.4,295l-6.1,4.1l-3.9,2.3l-3.4,3.7l-4,3.9l-3.2,0.8l-2.9,0.5l-5.5,2.6l-2.1,0.2l-3.4-3.1   l-5.2,0.6l-2.6-1.5l-2.4-1.4l-4.9,0.7l-10.2,1.6l-7.8,1.2l1.3,14.6l1.8,13.7l2.6,23.4l0.6,4.8l4.1-0.1l2.4-0.8l3.4,1.5l2.1,4.4   l5.1,0l1.9,2.1l1.8-0.1l2.5-1.3l2.5,0.4l2,1.5l1.7-2.1l2.3-1.3l2.1-0.7l0.6,2.7l1.8,1l3.5,2.3l2.2-0.1l1.1-1.1l-0.1-1.4l1.6-1.5   l0.2-5l1-3.9l1.5-1.4l1.5,0.9l0.8,1.2l1.2-0.2l-0.4-2.4l-0.6-0.6v-2.4l1-1.3l2.3-3.4l1.3-1.5l2.1,0.5l2.3-1.6l3.1-3.4l2.3-3.9   l0.2-5.4l0.5-5v-4.7l-1.1-3.1l1-1.5l0.9-1l-1.4-9.8L905.4,295z"/>
 <path id="MI" data-info="<div>State: Michigan</div><div>Capital: Lansing</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M755.6,182.1l1.8-2.1l2.2-0.8l5.4-3.9l2.3-0.6l0.5,0.5l-5.1,5.1l-3.3,1.9l-2.1,0.9L755.6,182.1z    M841.8,214.2l0.6,2.5l3.2,0.2l1.3-1.2c0,0-0.1-1.5-0.4-1.6c-0.3-0.2-1.6-1.9-1.6-1.9l-2.2,0.2l-1.6,0.2l-0.3,1.1L841.8,214.2z    M871.9,277.2l-3.2-8.2l-2.3-9.1l-2.4-3.2l-2.6-1.8l-1.6,1.1l-3.9,1.8l-1.9,5l-2.7,3.7l-1.1,0.6l-1.5-0.6c0,0-2.6-1.5-2.4-2.1   c0.2-0.6,0.5-5,0.5-5l3.4-1.3l0.8-3.4l0.6-2.6l2.4-1.6l-0.3-10l-1.6-2.3l-1.3-0.8l-0.8-2.1l0.8-0.8l1.6,0.3l0.2-1.6L850,231   l-1.3-2.6h-2.6l-4.5-1.5l-5.5-3.4h-2.7l-0.6,0.6l-1-0.5l-3.1-2.3l-2.9,1.8l-2.9,2.3l0.3,3.6l1,0.3l2.1,0.5l0.5,0.8l-2.6,0.8   l-2.6,0.3l-1.5,1.8l-0.3,2.1l0.3,1.6l0.3,5.5l-3.6,2.1l-0.6-0.2v-4.2l1.3-2.4l0.6-2.4l-0.8-0.8l-1.9,0.8l-1,4.2l-2.7,1.1l-1.8,1.9   l-0.2,1l0.6,0.8l-0.6,2.6l-2.3,0.5v1.1l0.8,2.4l-1.1,6.1l-1.6,4l0.6,4.7l0.5,1.1l-0.8,2.4l-0.3,0.8l-0.3,2.7l3.6,6l2.9,6.5l1.5,4.8   l-0.8,4.7l-1,6l-2.4,5.2l-0.3,2.7l-3.3,3.1l4.4-0.2l21.4-2.3l7.3-1l0.1,1.7l6.9-1.2l10.3-1.5l3.9-0.5l0.1-0.6l0.2-1.5l2.1-3.7   l2-1.7l-0.2-5.1l1.6-1.6l1.1-0.3l0.2-3.6l1.5-3l1.1,0.6l0.2,0.6l0.8,0.2l1.9-1L871.9,277.2z M741.5,211.2l0.7-0.6l2.7-0.8l3.6-2.3   v-1l0.6-0.6l6-1l2.4-1.9l4.4-2.1l0.2-1.3l1.9-2.9l1.8-0.8l1.3-1.8l2.3-2.3l4.4-2.4l4.7-0.5l1.1,1.1l-0.3,1l-3.7,1l-1.5,3.1   l-2.3,0.8l-0.5,2.4l-2.4,3.2l-0.3,2.6l0.8,0.5l1-1.1l3.6-2.9l1.3,1.3h2.3l3.2,1l1.5,1.1l1.5,3.1l2.7,2.7l3.9-0.2l1.5-1l1.6,1.3   l1.6,0.5l1.3-0.8h1.1l1.6-1l4-3.6l3.4-1.1l6.6-0.3l4.5-1.9l2.6-1.3l1.5,0.2v5.7l0.5,0.3l2.9,0.8l1.9-0.5l6.1-1.6l1.1-1.1l1.5,0.5v7   l3.2,3.1l1.3,0.6l1.3,1l-1.3,0.3l-0.8-0.3l-3.7-0.5l-2.1,0.6l-2.3-0.2l-3.2,1.5h-1.8l-5.8-1.3l-5.2,0.2l-1.9,2.6l-7,0.6l-2.4,0.8   l-1.1,3.1l-1.3,1.1l-0.5-0.2l-1.5-1.6l-4.5,2.4h-0.6l-1.1-1.6l-0.8,0.2l-1.9,4.4l-1,4l-3.2,7l-1.2-1l-1.4-1l-1.9-10.3l-3.5-1.4   l-2.1-2.3l-12.1-2.7l-2.9-1l-8.2-2.2l-7.9-1.1L741.5,211.2z"/>
 <path id="WY" data-info="<div>State: Wyoming</div><div>Capital: Cheyenne</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M528.3,243.8l-10.5-0.8l-32.1-3.3l-16.2-2.1l-28.3-4.1l-19.9-3l-1.4,11.2l-3.8,24.3l-5.3,30.4   l-1.5,10.5l-1.7,11.9l6.5,0.9l25.9,2.5l20.6,2.3l36.8,4.1l23.8,2.9l4.5-44.2l1.4-25.4L528.3,243.8z"/>
 <path id="MT" data-info="<div>State: Montana</div><div>Capital: Helena</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M530.7,222.3l0.6-11.2l2.3-24.8c0.5-5,1.1-8.5,1.4-15.4l0.9-14.6l-30.7-2.8L476,150l-29.3-4   l-32.3-5.3l-18.4-3.4l-32.7-6.9l-4.5,21.3l3.4,7.5l-1.4,4.6l1.8,4.6l3.2,1.4l4.6,10.8l2.7,3.2l0.5,1.1l3.4,1.1l0.5,2.1l-7.1,17.6   v2.5l2.5,3.2h0.9l4.8-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.2,5.3l2.7,12.6l3,2.5l0.9,0.7l1.8,2.3l-0.5,3.4l0.7,3.4l1.1,0.9l2.3-2.3h2.7l3.2,1.6   l2.5-0.9h4.1l3.7,1.6l2.7-0.5l0.5-3l3-0.7l1.4,1.4l0.5,3.2l1.8,1.4l1.5-11.6l20.7,3l28.2,4l16.6,1.9l31.4,3.5l11,1.5l1.1-15.4   L530.7,222.3z"/>
 <path id="ID" data-info="<div>State: Idaho</div><div>Capital: Boise</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M336.1,281c-22.6-4.3-14.1-2.8-21.1-4.4l4.4-17.5l4.3-17.7l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1   l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.3-4.4l0.4-9.7l3.7-16.5   l4.5-20.8l3.8-13.5l0.8-3.8l13,2.5l-4.2,21.5l2.9,7.7l-1.1,4.6l2,4.6l3.2,1.7l4.5,9.8l2.7,3.8l0.6,1.1l3.4,1.1l0.5,2.5l-6.9,16.8   l0.3,3.3l2.7,2.9l1.9,0.5l4.8-3.6l0.4-0.5l0.2,0.8l0.3,4.1l2.6,12.9l3.5,2.7l0.4,0.8l2.1,2.4l-0.8,2.8l0.7,3.8l1.9,0.9l2.1-1.6   l2.6-0.5l3.4,1.6l2.5-0.6l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.9-2.3l2.5-1.6l0.7,1.7l0.6,2.2l2.3,2.5l-3.8,24l-5.1,29l-4.2-0.3l-8.2-1.5   l-9.8-1.8l-12.2-2.4l-12.5-2.5l-8.5-1.8l-9.3-1.7L336.1,281z"/>
 <path id="WA" data-info="<div>State: Washington</div><div>Capital: Olympia</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M267.6,106.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.4l-1,3.9l-4.1,13.8l-4.5,20.8   l-3.2,16.1l-0.4,9.4l-13.2-3.9l-15.6-3.4l-13.7,0.6l-1.6-1.5l-5.3,1.9l-4-0.3l-2.7-1.8l-1.6,0.5l-4.2-0.2l-1.9-1.4l-4.8-1.7   l-1.4-0.2l-5-1.3l-1.8,1.5l-5.7-0.3l-4.8-3.8l0.2-0.8l0.1-7.9l-2.1-3.9l-4.1-0.7l-0.4-2.4l-2.5-0.6l-2.9-0.5l-1.8,1l-2.3-2.9   l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6   l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9   l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5V119l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.8l0.3-0.8L267.6,106.4z M258.1,112.3l2-0.2   l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6   l-1.5-2.3L258.1,112.3z"/>
 <path id="TX" data-info="<div>State: Texas</div><div>Capital: Austin</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M531.1,433.4l22.7,1.1l31.1,1.1l-2.3,23.5l-0.3,18.2l0.1,2.1l4.3,3.8l1.7,0.8l1.8,0.3l0.7-1.3   l0.9,0.9l1.7,0.5l1.6-0.7l1.1,0.4l-0.3,3.4l4.3,1l2.7,0.8l4,0.5l2.2,1.8l3.2-1.6l2.8,0.4l2,2.8l1.1,0.3l-0.2,2l3.1,1.2l2.8-1.8   l1.5,0.4l2.4,0.2l0.4,1.9l4.6,2l2.7-0.2l2-4.1h0.3l1.1,1.9l4.4,1l3.3,1.2l3.3,0.8l2.1-0.8l0.8-2.5h3.7l1.9,0.8l3.1-1.6h0.7l0.4,1.1   h4.3l2.4-1.3l1.7,0.3l1.4,1.9l2.9,1.7l3.5,1.1l2.7,1.4l2.4,1.6l3.3-0.9l1.9,1l0.5,10.1l0.3,9.7l0.7,9.5l0.5,4l2.7,4.6l1.1,4.1   l3.9,6.3l0.5,2.9l0.5,1l-0.7,7.5l-2.7,4.4l1,2.9l-0.4,2.5l-0.8,7.3l-1.4,2.7l0.6,4.4l-5.7,1.6l-9.9,4.5l-1,1.9l-2.6,1.9l-2.1,1.5   l-1.3,0.8l-5.7,5.3l-2.7,2.1l-5.3,3.2l-5.7,2.4l-6.3,3.4l-1.8,1.5l-5.8,3.6l-3.4,0.6l-3.9,5.5l-4,0.3l-1,1.9l2.3,1.9l-1.5,5.5   l-1.3,4.5l-1.1,3.9l-0.8,4.5l0.8,2.4l1.8,7l1,6.1l1.8,2.7l-1,1.5l-3.1,1.9l-5.7-3.9l-5.5-1.1l-1.3,0.5l-3.2-0.6l-4.2-3.1l-5.2-1.1   l-7.6-3.4l-2.1-3.9l-1.3-6.5l-3.2-1.9l-0.6-2.3l0.6-0.6l0.3-3.4l-1.3-0.6l-0.6-1l1.3-4.4l-1.6-2.3l-3.2-1.3l-3.4-4.4l-3.6-6.6   l-4.2-2.6l0.2-1.9l-5.3-12.3l-0.8-4.2l-1.8-1.9l-0.2-1.5l-6-5.3l-2.6-3.1v-1.1l-2.6-2.1l-6.8-1.1l-7.4-0.6l-3.1-2.3l-4.5,1.8   l-3.6,1.5l-2.3,3.2l-1,3.7l-4.4,6.1l-2.4,2.4l-2.6-1l-1.8-1.1l-1.9-0.6l-3.9-2.3v-0.6l-1.8-1.9l-5.2-2.1l-7.4-7.8l-2.3-4.7v-8.1   l-3.2-6.5l-0.5-2.7l-1.6-1l-1.1-2.1l-5-2.1l-1.3-1.6l-7.1-7.9l-1.3-3.2l-4.7-2.3l-1.5-4.4l-2.6-2.9l-1.9-0.5l-0.6-4.7l8,0.7l29,2.7   l29,1.6l2.3-23.8l3.9-55.6l1.6-18.7l1.4,0 M631.2,667.3l-0.6-7.1l-2.7-7.2l-0.6-7l1.5-8.2l3.3-6.9l3.5-5.4l3.2-3.6l0.6,0.2   l-4.8,6.6l-4.4,6.5l-2,6.6l-0.3,5.2l0.9,6.1l2.6,7.2l0.5,5.2l0.2,1.5L631.2,667.3z"/>
 <path id="CA" data-info="<div>State: California</div><div>Capital: Sacramento</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M310.7,486.8l3.8-0.5l1.5-2l0.7-1.9l-3.2-0.1l-1.1-1.8l0.8-1.7l0-6.2l2.2-1.3l2.7-2.6l0.4-4.9   l1.6-3.5l1.9-2.1l3.3-1.7l1.3-0.7l0.8-1.5l-0.9-0.9l-1-1.5l-0.9-5.3l-2.9-5.2l0.1-2.8l-2.2-3.2l-15-23.2l-19.4-28.7l-22.4-33   l-12.7-19.5l1.8-7.2l6.8-25.9l8.1-31.4l-12.4-3.3l-13.5-3.4l-12.6-4.1l-7.5-2.1l-11.4-3l-7.1-2.4l-1.6,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8   l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5   l2.3,4.8l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6   l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9   l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.8l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2   l2.9,4.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L310.7,486.8z M222.8,437l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1   l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L222.8,437z M224.7,437l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L224.7,437z M245.4,456.8l1.8,2.3   l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V456.8z M244,465.5l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9   s0-2.2,0-2.2L244,465.5z"/>
 <path id="AZ" data-info="<div>State: Arizona</div><div>Capital: Phoenix</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M311.7,487.5l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25.1,2.7   l2.5-12.5l3.8-27.2l7-52.9l4.3-31l-24.6-3.7l-27.2-4.6l-33.4-6.3l-2.9,18.1l-0.5,0.5l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1   h-0.9l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7   l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l-0.1,5.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7l-1.5,2.2L311.7,487.5z"/>
 <path id="NV" data-info="<div>State: Nevada</div><div>Capital: Carson City</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M314.7,277.6l21,4.5l9.7,1.9l9.3,1.8l6.6,1.6l-0.6,5.9l-3.5,17.3l-4.1,20l-1.9,9.7l-2.2,13.3   l-3.2,16.4l-3.5,15.7l-2,10.2l-2.5,16.8l-0.5,1.1l-1.1,2.5l-1.9-0.1l-1.1-2.7l-2.7-0.5l-1.4-1l-2,0.3l-0.9,0.7l-1.3,1.3l-0.4,7   l-0.5,1.7l-0.4,12.1l-1.3,1.7l-1.9-2.3l-14.5-22.7l-19.4-29L263.6,349l-12.4-18.6l1.6-6.6l7-25.9l7.9-31.3l33.6,8.1l13.7,3"/>
 <path id="UT" data-info="<div>State: Utah</div><div>Capital: Salt Lake City</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M427,409.3l-24.6-3.5l-26.6-4.9l-33.8-6l1.6-9.2l3.2-15.2L350,354l2.2-13.6l1.9-8.9l3.8-20.5   l3.5-17.5l1.1-5.6l12.7,2.3l12,2.1l10.3,1.8l8.3,1.4l3.7,0.5l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9l-2.1,22l-3.2,22.6   l-3.8,27.8l-1.7,11.1L427,409.3z"/>
 <g id="DC">
  <path id="path58" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M975.8,353.8l-1.1-1.6l-1-0.8l1.1-1.6l2.2,1.5L975.8,353.8z"/>
  <circle id="circle60" data-info="<div>Washington DC</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.5" cx="975.3" cy="351.8" r="5"/>
 </g>
 
 
 
 
 
</g>
<path id="path67" fill="none" stroke="#A9A9A9" stroke-width="2" d="M385,593v55l36,45 M174,525h144l67,68h86l53,54v46"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: It's worth noting the the OP seems to have the beginnings of something similar: `window.open(link,'_blank')`. It just doesn't appear to be finished, as there is no associated `<a>` or `href`.